# Create CNN model architecture diagram in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, graphviz

I followed the tutorial to create visually graphical representation of CNN model using this: https://keras.io/visualization/

My code at the moment is as follows:

```
from keras.utils import plot_model
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
import numpy as np

model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet')
plot_model(model, to_file='model.png')
```

When I use the aforementioned code I am able to create a graphical representation (using Graphviz) of ResNet50 and save it in 'model.png'. But I want to create block diagram of the CNN model with the layers instead. An example of my desired output is as follows:
[image]

Any idea how I can achieve the aforementioned block diagram programatically instead of just generating the graph diagram of the CNN model?

Comment: Check out this cool repo : https://github.com/HarisIqbal88/PlotNeuralNet

Comment: I have tried that. unfrotunately, it is not working at the moment and have also raised an issue related to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a comprehensive list of existing solutions (not only for Keras): [How do you visualize neural network architectures?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12851/how-do-you-visualize-neural-network-architectures/44571#44571).

Pay attention on [Netron](https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron).

Comment: thank you for the reply. Just a quick question before I use Netron: Can I download the final block diagram as a png or pdf? 
I have tried the Netscope one but I do not seem to be able to download the network summary/diagram as an image file.

Comment: I did not use it, unfortunately. But you can always make a screenshot :)